# What should I do to apply for a Schengen visa without income tax return?

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, proof-of-funds

I would like to apply for a Schengen visa to travel to Florence, Italy between 30th June to 8th July where I will be attending EuroPython. My request for the grant has been approved by EuroPython committee so accommodation and lunch are totally free for that period. For the visa there is a requirement for 3 years income tax returns, but I start to work last year and I don't even earn enough to file an income return. I would like to know how can I get a visa without an income tax return or what substitute documents I have to submit for the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not apply for a tourist visa, but apply for an "[invitation visa](http://www.vfs-italy.co.in/PDF/Invitation%20check%20list.pdf)" instead. You ask the EuroPython to send you an invitation letter and then use that to [get a visa](http://www.vfs-italy.co.in/application_form.html). The [invitation letter](http://www.ambnewdelhi.esteri.it/NR/rdonlyres/1AEC11FF-C3AF-48CD-8AEC-67A49A093A22/58698/Moduloaffari1.pdf) should be in Italian.